# Can't use newly made database

Tags: jquery, sql-server

I'm trying to create a database script. But for some reason it won't allow me to use the database which I just created.

```
create database KnittingKnightsShop;

use KnittingKnightsShop

create table Profil
(
    id integer identity not null,
    unique(id),
    primary key(id),
    email varchar(MAX) not null,
    phone varchar(50) not null,
    facebookId varchar(MAX) not null,
    isAdministrator bit not null
)
```

The error occours at the **use KnittingKnightsShop** line. It says that the database doesn't exist. But I've just created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database isn't created since the `CREATE` statement hasn't been sent to the server by the point the script gets to `USE` statement. You have to use `GO` statement (batch separator) after `CREATE`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

```
create database KnittingKnightsShop;
GO
use KnittingKnightsShop
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create database KnittingKnightsShop;
go
use KnittingKnightsShop
go
create table Profil
(
    id integer identity not null,
    unique(id),
    primary key(id),
    email varchar(MAX) not null,
    phone varchar(50) not null,
    facebookId varchar(MAX) not null,
    isAdministrator bit not null
)
go
```